# Wiki software with API so my chatbot can write to it

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, self-hosted, wiki

So I have been looking around for some options for our project wiki. My needs are simple enough:

1. User login, user groups, ability to allow some pages only to be edited by certain users/groups
2. Editing API to allow bots to write / update pages etc (or RPC)
3. Syntax highlighting
4. Ease of use, for non-tech types
5. Good looking

I really like the look of [wikijs](https://wiki.js.org/) but unfortunately it has no API / RPC support.

On the other end of the spectrum I tried out [dokuwiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) which has tons of features but looks like crap and fails on point 4 & 5 above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with [xwiki](https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome) which has the best tradeoff between the essential features I need (RPC) and looks.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is [star7th/showdoc: ShowDoc is a tool greatly applicable for an IT team to share documents online](https://github.com/star7th/showdoc)  which provides a nice interface and API.